# Pandas : Datetimeindex and Intervalindex intersection

Tags: python, pandas, performance, numpy, datetimeindex

I have very long time series for which i need to set values within intervals of certain events to `np.nan`. `measures` is a `datetimeindex`ed dataframe and `events` is a distinct `datetimeindex` distinct.

Measures looks like:

```
| index               | measure  |
|---------------------|----------|
| 1970-01-01 00:00:15 | 0.471331 |
| 1970-01-01 00:02:37 | 0.069177 |
| 1970-01-01 00:03:59 | 0.955357 |
| 1970-01-01 00:06:17 | 0.107815 |
| 1970-01-01 00:06:24 | 0.046558 |
| 1970-01-01 00:06:25 | 0.056558 |
| 1970-01-01 00:08:12 | 0.837405 |
```

For example if there were only a single event at timestamp `1970-01-01 00:06:21` and the intervals for removing values was +/- 5 seconds, the output would be:

```
| index               | measure  |
|---------------------|----------|
| 1970-01-01 00:00:15 | 0.471331 |
| 1970-01-01 00:02:37 | 0.069177 |
| 1970-01-01 00:03:59 | 0.955357 |
| 1970-01-01 00:06:17 | np.nan   |
| 1970-01-01 00:06:24 | np.nan   |
| 1970-01-01 00:06:25 | np.nan   |
| 1970-01-01 00:08:12 | 0.837405 |
```

Currently I'm interating over the events using `.loc`:

```
for i in range(events.shape[0]):
    measures.loc[events[i] - pd.Timedelta("4min"):\
                 events[i] + pd.Timedelta("1min") \
        ] = np.nan
```

Now this works but takes too long both dataframes are large (events : 10k rows, measures 1.5m rows). Therefore I couldn't construct a boolean index like so:

```
measure_index = measures.index.to_numpy()
left_bounds = (events - pd.Timedelta("4min")).to_numpy()
right_bounds = (events + pd.Timedelta("1min")).to_numpy()
# The following product wouldn't fit in memory even with boolean dtype.
left_bool_array = measure_index >= left_bounds.reshape((-1,1)) 
right_bool_array = measure_index <= right_bounds.reshape((-1,1))
mask = np.sum( left_bool_array & right_bool_array.T ,axis= 0)
```

Left joining the events on measures or reindexing events is also out of the question as they take too long.

I then ran into pd.intervalindex:

```
left_bound = events - pd.Timedelta("4min")
right_bound = events + pd.Timedelta("1min")
interval_index=pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(left_bound,right_bound)
```

`Intervalindex` index has `.contains()` method which takes a scalar and returns "a boolean mask whether the value is contained in the Intervals". However for my use case I'd need to loop trough the measures frame and sum the boolean array for each row. I'm looking for a method like so:

> pandas.IntervalIndex.intersect(input: array_like) -> boolean_array (same shape as input)

With each element in the output representing whether the corresponding input value is in **any** of the intervals.

Similar but different questions:

- Interval lookup with interval index: [Fastest way to merge pandas dataframe on ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179362/fastest-way-to-merge-pandas-dataframe-on-ranges/46179615)
- Quite similar but the suggested solutions (merges) are not applicable [Match IntervalIndex as part of a MultiIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49523991/match-intervalindex-as-part-of-a-multiindex)
- If only I had the same indexes and a single interval per row to lookup [Best way to join / merge by range in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367672/best-way-to-join-merge-by-range-in-pandas/44601120#44601120)

**Edit** performance of options discussed in below answer:

*len(events) = 10000, len(measures) = 1525229*

- pandas `.loc` : 10.5 seconds

```py
for _ in range(10):  
    left_bound = dilution_copy.index - pd.Timedelta("4min")
    right_bound = dilution_copy.index + pd.Timedelta("1min")

    for left,right in zip(left_bound,right_bound):
        measure_copy.loc[left:right]=np.nan
```

- Staircase : 13.9 seconds

```py
for _ in range(10):  
    sf = sc.Stairs(start=measure_copy.index, end = measure_copy.index[1:], value=measure_copy.values)
    mask = sc.Stairs(start=dilution_copy.index-pd.Timedelta('4 min'), end=dilution_copy.index+pd.Timedelta('1 min'))
    masked = sf.mask(mask)
    result = masked.sample(measure_copy.index, include_index=True)
```

- Bisect + `.iloc`: 35.1 seconds

```py
for _ in range(10):
    left_bound = dilution_copy.index - pd.Timedelta("4min")
    right_bound = dilution_copy.index + pd.Timedelta("1min")

    for left,right in zip(left_bound,right_bound):
        measure_copy.iloc[bisect(measure_copy.index, left):bisect(measure_copy.index, right)]=np.nan
```

Comment: Can you provide a simplified (shortened) version of `measures`, `events` and the expected final output?

Comment: @Mortz Just did, but the question remains how to do it efficiently for large dataframes.

Comment: 1) work on timestamps instead of datetimes. 2) work with numpy arrays instead of dataframes. 3) do this simultaneous iterating over events and measures (which you mentioned in comment below) 4) use numba or other compiler to do this iteration faster (as it will be bottleneck for sure)

Answer (score 1):

If your `measures` data is already sorted (or if it is not too time consuming to sort once) - you can think of using `bisect`.

Here is <s>an approximate</s> more complete solution:

- Check every element of `events` for where it can be "inserted" in
  the `measures`
- Check if the timestamps on either side of this "insertion point" are within 5 seconds
- If yes, set to nan

```py
def bisect_loop():
    for event in events:
        bisect_point = bisect.bisect(measures.index, event)
        keep_looking_lower = True
        while keep_looking_lower:
            lower_side_index = max(0, bisect_point - 1)
            lower_side_diff = event - measures.index[lower_side_index]
            if lower_side_diff.seconds < 5:
                measures.loc[measures.index[lower_side_index]] = np.nan
                bisect_point = max(0, bisect_point - 1)
            elif lower_side_diff.seconds >=5 or bisect_point == 0:
                keep_looking_lower = False
        keep_looking_higher = True
        while keep_looking_higher:
            higher_side_index = min(len(measures.index), bisect_point)
            higher_side_diff = event - measures.index[higher_side_index]
            if higher_side_diff.seconds < 5:
                measures.loc[measures.index[higher_side_index]] = np.nan
                bisect_point = min(len(measures.index), bisect_point + 1)
            elif higher_side_diff.seconds >=5 or bisect_point == len(measures.index):
                keep_looking_higher = False
```

Here are some stats on a dummy dataset with 150 measures and 10 events -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2000]*150, 'month': [2]*150, 'day': [12]*150, 'hour': np.random.choice(range(1), 150), 'minute': np.random.choice(range(60), 150), 'second': np.random.choice(range(60), 150)})

timestamps = pd.to_datetime(df)
measures = pd.concat([timestamps, pd.Series(np.random.rand(150))], axis=1)
measures = measures.set_index(0)
measures = measures.sort_index()

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2000]*150, 'month': [2]*150, 'day': [12]*150, 'hour': np.random.choice(range(24), 150), 'minute': np.random.choice(range(60), 150), 'second': np.random.choice(range(60), 150)})
events = pd.to_datetime(df).sample(10).reset_index(drop=True)

%timeit op_loop() # This is your loc based approach that is working
8.74 ms Â± 126 Âµs per loop (mean Â± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%timeit bisect_loop()
3.22 ms Â± 45.8 Âµs per loop (mean Â± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: This would work if we removed only 1 point on each side. But i'm trying to remove all point within that interval. Sorry my question wasn't clear enough, I'll update the example.

Comment: Yes, I understand. That's why I said it is an approximate solution. You could scan the adjacent elements to the `bisection_point` with a `while` loop and stop once you find the points which are more than 5s off

Comment: Don't you think running a while loop on each side would be slower than .loc[lower_bound:higher_bound] ? The approximate frequency of measures is 5 seconds. That's 60 iterations per event. But I'll try it.

Comment: My sense is that if an `event` has to change a lot of `measures` to a `nan`, then yes - I would expect it to be slow. But as you say, if the approximate frequency of measures is ~5s, then each event will have to only look at a couple of `while` iterations.

Comment: Better would be to find the index of the upper and lower bound with bisect and set the values in that index range to np.nan, I think.

Comment: Yet this is still O(interval * logN * len(events)). As both indexes are sorted, it feels like it should be possible to do it in O(len(measures)) maybe by iterating trough both indexes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Can be solved with [staircase](https://staircase.dev), a package built on pandas and numpy for working with (mathematical) step functions.

Setup:

```
measures = pd.Series(
    [0.471331, 0.069177, 0.955357, 0.107815, 0.046558, 0.056558, 0.837405],
    index = pd.DatetimeIndex([
        pd.Timestamp("1970-1-1 00:00:15"),
        pd.Timestamp("1970-1-1 00:02:37"),
        pd.Timestamp("1970-1-1 00:03:59"),
        pd.Timestamp("1970-1-1 00:06:17"),
        pd.Timestamp("1970-1-1 00:06:24"),
        pd.Timestamp("1970-1-1 00:06:25"),
        pd.Timestamp("1970-1-1 00:08:12"),
    ])
)

events = pd.DatetimeIndex(['1970-01-01 00:06:21'])
```

Solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import staircase as sc

sf = sc.Stairs(start=measures.index, end = measures.index[1:], value=measures.values)
mask = sc.Stairs(start=events-pd.Timedelta('5 seconds'), end=events+pd.Timedelta('5 seconds'))
masked = sf.mask(mask)
result = masked.sample(measures.index, include_index=True)
```

**Why it works**

*1st line*: create a step function which is made up of intervals whose endpoints are the index of `measures`.  The last interval, which starts at 1970-01-01 00:08:12, has no end point and will be of infinite length

*2nd line*: create a step function where the times in your `events` variable are the centers of intervals in the step function, and the endpoints are +/- 5 seconds from the center.  No problem at all if any intervals overlap.

*3rd line*: mask the first step function with the second step function, which sets values in the first step function to NaN whenever the second step function is non-zero

*4th line*: evaluates the `masked` step function at your event times

**note**:
I am the creator of staircase.  Please feel free to reach out with feedback or questions if you have any.

Comment: This could work but having glanced at the source codes i highly doubt it would be faster. It has multiple concatenations and iterates trough both series more than once.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know what the timings are if you can test it on the full example.  The internals are mostly numpy and pandas vectorised functions - no "for" loops.

Answer (score 0):

One option is with the [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/).

Reusing @Riley's data:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df1 = measures.rename('measure').reset_index()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(events)
df2 = (df2.assign(start = df2[0] -pd.Timedelta('5 seconds'), 
                  end = df2[0] +pd.Timedelta('5 seconds'))
          .drop(columns=0)
       )
(
df1
.conditional_join(
    df2, 
    ('index', 'start', '>='), 
    ('index', 'end', '<='), 
    how = 'left')
.assign(measure = lambda df: np.where(df.start.isna(), 
                                      df.measure, 
                                      np.nan))
.loc[:, ['index', 'measure']]
)

                index   measure
0 1970-01-01 00:00:15  0.471331
1 1970-01-01 00:02:37  0.069177
2 1970-01-01 00:03:59  0.955357
3 1970-01-01 00:06:17       NaN
4 1970-01-01 00:06:24       NaN
5 1970-01-01 00:06:25       NaN
6 1970-01-01 00:08:12  0.837405
```