# Pandas merge on date range on multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have dataframe of events with start and end dates like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Event": ["S1", "K1", "S2", "S3", "A1"],
                    "Start": [datetime(2022,1,4), datetime(2022,1,15), datetime(2022,9,12), datetime(2022,11,11), datetime(2022,5,29)],
                    "End": [datetime(2022,1,19), datetime(2022,1, 29), datetime(2022,9,27), datetime(2022,11,22), datetime(2022,6,15)]
                   })
```

Note: The `"Event"` column may not have unique values.

I have another dataframe which contains all the holidays:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Holidays": [datetime(2022,1,1), datetime(2022,1,6), datetime(2022,1,13), ....]})
```

I want to know for every event how many holidays are there in between the start and end date both inclusive. My solution:

```
df['holiday_count'] = df.apply(lambda x: len(set(pd.date_range(x['Start'], x['End'])).intersection(set(holidays['Holidays']))), axis=1)
```

I realize that my solution is quite inefficient for large dataset of `df1`. Here are a few things which I tried:

1. Since, it is not an exact match, `df1.merge` wouldn't help.
2. I tried using `pd.merge_asof`, however, the joins count only to 1. Over here, the start and end period may contain multiple holidays or no holidays as well.
3. I tried using `pd.IntervalIndex`. The issue over there I faced is `KeyError` for those ranges where there were no holidays.
4. `cross` merge followed by filter is one option, but I think, it'd have a high memory imprint which I want to avoid.
5. Although didn't try, but people were suggesting to use `pandas_sql`. However, there were comments stating it is slow method.

These trials were based on several stackoverflow questions in the past like:

1. [Best way to join / merge by range in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367672/best-way-to-join-merge-by-range-in-pandas)
2. [Fastest way to merge pandas dataframe on ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46179362/fastest-way-to-merge-pandas-dataframe-on-ranges)
3. [Merge pandas dataframes where one value is between two others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others)
4. [How to join two dataframes for which column values are within a certain range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525786/how-to-join-two-dataframes-for-which-column-values-are-within-a-certain-range)

Comment: Have you tested your code before ? It gives an `AttributeError` for *pd.Dataframe* and a `TypeError: Cannot convert input [0   2022-01-04..`.

Comment: @Timeless for `df1`, I wrote `Dataframe` instead of `DataFrame` (with capital F). Hence, the attribute error. Now, code to define `df1` is working for me. Apologies for the error in markup.

Comment: Of course, one need to import `import pandas as pd` and `from datetime import datetime`. Will edit the code for clarity.

Comment: `df1['holiday_count'] = ..` still gives a `SyntaxError` and a `TypeError` but anyways, I posted an answer below if you're tempted to give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) *approach* :

```
sdates, edates = df1["Start"].values, df1["End"].values
hdates = df2["Holidays"].values[:, None]

df1["holiday_count"] = np.sum((hdates >= sdates) & (hdates <= end_dates), axis=0)

# 801 µs ± 45.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Output :

```
print(df1)

  Event      Start        End  holiday_count
0    S1 2022-01-04 2022-01-19              2
1    K1 2022-01-15 2022-01-29              0
2    S2 2022-09-12 2022-09-27              0
3    S3 2022-11-11 2022-11-22              0
4    A1 2022-05-29 2022-06-15              0
```

Comment: Your solution is a significantly faster than mine. Will mark as accepted solution in a day unless there is a better solution which may come up.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest this is an alternative solution to your question

```
 # Function to count the number of holidays between two dates (inclusive)
def count_holidays(start_date, end_date, holidays):
    return sum(start_date <= holiday <= end_date for holiday in holidays)

# Merge df1 and df2 on Event
merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on="Event", right_on="Event", how="left")

# Count holidays for each event
merged_df["HolidaysCount"] = merged_df.apply(lambda row: count_holidays(row["Start"], row["End"], row["Holidays"]), axis=1)

# Drop the Holidays column
merged_df.drop("Holidays", axis=1, inplace=True)

print(merged_df)
```

Comment: I do not think this is any better if not worse solution than mine as your `apply` function has loops with constant re-assignment of `curr_date` variable.

Comment: I just avoiding the loop and modified my above code

Comment: I do not think code for `merged_df` will work because there is no `right_on="Event"` column in `df2`. Regardless of it, if I understand correctly, you're trying to create a cross merge and then computing the holiday count which fits the date range. As I mentioned in my original post, this would have high memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

This is an inequality join, which is solved efficiently with [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
# for better performance, if you can
# install the dev version:
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git

(df1
.conditional_join(
    df2, 
    ('Start', 'Holidays', '<='), 
    ('End', 'Holidays', '>='), 
    how = 'left')
.groupby(df1.columns.tolist(), sort = False)
.count()
)
                             Holidays
Event Start      End                 
S1    2022-01-04 2022-01-19         2
K1    2022-01-15 2022-01-29         0
S2    2022-09-12 2022-09-27         0
S3    2022-11-11 2022-11-22         0
A1    2022-05-29 2022-06-15         0
```

Under the hood, it uses binary search, instead of a cartesian join. For large data, this offers more performance/efficiency.